# suppose $r$ is the second largest eigenvalue of adjacency matrix of $srg(n,k,\lambda ,\mu)$,prove that $r< \frac{k}{2}$

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

suppose that $G$ is strongly regular graph $srg(n,k,\lambda ,\mu)$,suppose $r$ is the second largest eigenvalue of adjacency matrix,prove that $r< \frac{k}{2}$ ,in addition $r\leq \frac{1}{2}(k-1)$ unless $G=C_5$ .

we know that if $G$ is not complete then $r=\frac{1}{2}((\lambda-\mu)+\sqrt{(\lambda-\mu)^{2}+4(k-\mu)})$

I supposed that $2r<k$ with some calculation and using $k\geq 2\lambda -\mu +3$ I arrived $k\mu +k>k$ now if this inequality is right then I will back this way,but I couldn't show that this inequality is right,and maybe it is not right at all,

it will be great to help me with ,thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you would like to prove $k\mu+k>k$? It is trivial, since $\mu>0$.

Comment: btw., I think the coefficient 1/2 also should be used for the square root in the formula for the eigenvalue. i.e. $$r=\frac12\left(\lambda-\mu+\sqrt{(\lambda-\mu)^2+4(k-\mu)}\right).$$

Comment: yes,your right ,my calculation is wrong!I don't know what to say ,just sorry!

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to everyone ;) btw. who is teaching you algebraic graph theory?

Comment: dr akbari,but my mistake not him!

Comment: my question was totally unrelated to your mistake :) I was just curios, there are just a few people working in algebraic graph theory. I met him personally 3-4 years ago. He is a very smart guy.

Comment: it is marvellous for me that you met my teacher,I really love this part of math,everything I like is together:graph,linear algebra!but I am not smart,but I am trying my best,and I should thank you because your helping on my questions.